# One login script, two tables

Tags: php

I have a website for my school I am designing.

I am struggling how to work this for my script, but there are two sections to the website. If a teacher logs in, from the table lesson_teachers, it should redirect them to lesson.php. If a student logs in, from the table users, it redirects them to home.php.

I think the select query for the teachers table may be something like this:

```
  SELECT id FROM lesson_teachers WHERE username='$user_login' AND password='$md5password_login' LIMIT 1
```

I am trying to fit that select statement into my login script below, so that people with usernames and passwords in both tables can log into one script.

```
               if (isset($_POST["user_login"]) && isset($_POST["password_login"])) {
$user_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["user_login"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
$password_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password_login"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
$md5password_login = md5($password_login);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$user_login' AND password='$md5password_login' LIMIT 1"); // query the person
//Check for their existance
$userCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); //Count the number of rows returned
if ($userCount == 1) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
         $id = $row["id"];
}
     $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
     $_SESSION["user_login"] = $user_login;
     $_SESSION["password_login"] = $password_login;
     exit("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0\">");
    } else {
    echo 'That information is incorrect, try again';
    exit();
}
      }
```

Comment: If this is the kind of coding they teach at your school, then your teachers should be ashamed. `mysql_*` extension is being deprecated... please use `PDO` (or `mysqli_*`) instead. Also: don't use regex to "sanitize" user input, but try using the escape functions or - better yet: _prepared statements_, which is why you should, once again, switch to `PDO`

Comment: @KaiQing: Oh, there's only so much you can say in 600 chars, I stuck to the first 3 lines, and the `mysql_*`-thing, because that just _really_ gets my goat

Answer (score 3):

Your user table should either have a roles relation or at least a tinyint 1 field (0 for student, 1 for teacher) in your user table so you don't have to use 2 tables to achieve this.

Pretending I agreed with the query, this is what it might look like:

```
SELECT id, level FROM users WHERE username='$user_login' AND password='$md5password_login' LIMIT 1
```

where level is 0 for student, 1 for teacher. Any data relevant to either student or teacher on its own could be stored in a relation table.

Then you could say:

```
if($row['level'] == 1)
{
    header('Location: /teacher-url');
    exit;
}
else
{
    header('Location: /student-url');
    exit;
}
```

Now for the extra nuggets:
Please don't use this method for comparing passwords. You could basically login as another user accidentally or by happenstance if you were trying to hack since it strips characters. So `"pa_s$sw==0ord"` turns into `"password"`

Just run a sha1 (or better) encryption comparison on the posted input versus the stored sha1 encrypted password in the DB. That's the best real comparison to user passwords vs input.
And storing a password in $_SESSION just plain makes no sense. Why would you ever use it like this? Perhaps if you tell we can point you in a better direction.

And as Elias said, use PDO or mysqli. They will sanitize correctly amid the many many other reasons to use them over mysql_ functions.

I should add that we are all aware of how to actually answer your question. We know you want to know HOW to do it with what you've got. But we refuse. Because this habit should be cleaned before it becomes a nightmare. Not trying to be deliberately rude or anything, but a well planned database structure and use of PDO or mysqli will save you tons of time in both database and code. Look into relation tables, the concept of "roles" and sanitizing user input. From that you can construct the user system in a way that makes sense.

Comment: And salt the password! Also, there's far better options than either SHA and MD5 (both of which are far too fast to be well suited), such as PBKDF2 (and others).

Comment: true. I should have clarified that sha1 is not the BEST but rather what I meant is that raw comparison salted, hashed and all is the best. Raw input vs stored input. no interference between the two. All hashed though since hash is not considered interference.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you will only find 1 match per user/password pair,
so instead of

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
    $id = $row["id"];
}
```

you can simply do

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$id = $row["id"];
```

As for the teach/student redirect, you will need a hidden variable in the login from to identity type= teacher or student

then based on this variable, you can do

```
if ($type=='student')
  header('location:home.php');
if ($type=='teacher')
  header('location:lession.php');
```

after setting your session variables.

Comment: And what populates that hidden field? Probably shouldn't rely on the user to specify